# ul list that floats into scroll area

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float

Im wanting a way to make my un-ordered list flow to the right into a scroll-able area instead of floating to a new line when there are to many. I have read many other things that are similar on the Internets and on stack-overflow but nothing made what I was wanting or worked properly. How can this be accomplished?.

Also would there be a way to make this scroll-able area work with a JQuery button? So when a user presses it it will jump over to the next item.

JSFiddle: [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/wgDWs/)

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, code, del, dfn, em, img, q, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td { border: 0; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-size: 100%; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0; margin-bottom: 1.4em; }
caption, th, td { text-align: left; font-weight: 400; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after { content: ""; }
blockquote, q { quotes:  }
a img { border: none; }

.series_container { margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 10px; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: medium #F0F0F0 solid; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; overflow-x: scroll; }
.series_table { width: 100%; font-size: 12px; }
.series_block { display: inline; text-align: center; width: 24.6%; margin: 0 .1em; color: #FFFFFF; float: left; list-style-type: none; transition: all 0.25s; position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; }
.series_grayed { display: none; }
.series { display: table; background: #202020; width: 100%; height: 70px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0; }
.series_figure { font-size: 24px; vertical-align: middle; display: table-cell; }
.series_number { font-weight: bold; display: block; }
.series_tenure { font-size: 11px; }
.features { background: #F0F0F0; color: #333333; }
.features li { padding: 8px 7.5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #B6B6B6; font-size: 11px; list-style-type: none; height: 40px; }
.series_footer { background: #F0F0F0; padding-bottom: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px; }
.series_block:hover { -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); box-shadow: 0 0 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); -webkit-transform: scale(1.03) translateY(-5px); -moz-transform: scale(1.03) translateY(-5px); -o-transform: scale(1.03) translateY(-5px); -ms-transform: scale(1.03) translateY(-5px); transform: scale(1.03) translateY(-5px); z-index: 1; border-bottom: 0 none; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; }
.series_block:hover .series { background: #004687; }
```

Currently How it Works:

[image: Current Image]

How I'm wanting it to look except all items are just a scroll-able field:

[image: Wanting Image]

Comment: You want a single row of `li` items, and the `ul` to scroll sideways, right? Is it okay if they items are fixed-width instead of 24% as they are now?

Comment: Yes thats whats im looking for. The fixed width is fine because its something I could work with. Im not sold on the current width anyway. Just something i set to help it fit perfectly into the space I had.

Comment: Have either of the answers provided solved your question, or are their additional issues we can help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What's Going On

You can do with with pure CSS, using `white-space` and `inline-block`. I've got is 90% working, but I'm having an issue with certain boxes being pushed down. It's something to do with the last `li` inside each item `li`.

**EDIT:** When the final box only has a single line, it pushes the box down. Odd, and I'm not sure why. There should be a way to fix it though.

**EDIT 2** Looks like the offender is different lengths of text inside the `inline-block` `li`s. To fix this, we need to control the extra overflowing text.

We can set `overflow: hidden` to the `.feature li`s, which will prevent any from overflowing onto three lines. Combined with this, I'd be careful with the text content and make sure it's all pretty similar length.

---

## Code

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wgDWs/5/)

#### Original CSS:

```
.series_table { width: 100%; font-size: 12px; }
.series_block { display: inline; text-align: center; width: 24.6%; margin: 0 .1em; color: #FFFFFF; float: left; list-style-type: none; transition: all 0.25s; position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; }
...
.features li {padding: 8px 7.5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #B6B6B6; font-size: 11px; list-style-type: none; height: 40px; }
```

#### New CSS:

```
.series_table { width: 100%; font-size: 12px; white-space: nowrap;}
.series_block { display: inline-block; text-align: center; width: 200px; margin: 0 .1em; color: #FFFFFF; list-style-type: none; transition: all 0.25s; position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; border-bottom: 1px solid transparent; white-space: normal;}
...
.features li {overflow:hidden; padding: 8px 7.5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #B6B6B6; font-size: 11px; list-style-type: none; height: 40px; }
```

#### Key Changes:

Add `white-space:nowrap` to `.series_table`.

Add `display:inline-block`, and `white-space:normal` to `.series_block`, and remove the `float`ing.

Add `overflow:hidden` to `.features li`.

---

## Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had a few issues myself trying to get this to work until I realized i had clears after every 4 lines of code. Once those were gone this worked flawlessly.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that I removed them in my example. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it scroll to the overflowed area, the width of `.series_table` is needed to be a fixed width calculated according to its list items. Calculating this with pure CSS is not possible. With a little help of jquery we can calculate the width of this element and this way we can make it scrollable.

I've made the `width` of `.series_table`'s list items' `200px`, you can change it as you want.

[**Fiddle link.**](http://jsfiddle.net/wgDWs/2/)

```
$(function() {
    var $series_table = $('.series_table'),
        $series_table_item = $series_table.find('.series_block'),
        item_num = $series_table_item.length,
        table_width = item_num * $series_table_item.outerWidth(true);

    $series_table.css('width', table_width + 'px');
});
```